How is Viterbi algorithm traceback implemented?
I have written a basic Viterbi decoder in MATLAB (for decoding convolutional codes), which currently assumes an unlimited traceback length. That works fine, but practical (hardware) implementations typically need to limit the traceback length. For example, with constraint length $K$, we might limit the traceback length to $5K$.
I don't really understand how to make that work. Is traceback repeated for every encoded bit (excluding the first $5K-1$ bits) like a sliding window? Or is traceback done once per $5K$ encoded bits in a block-wise manner?
I have scoured countless textbooks and websites, but the only reference that (only barely) touches this topic is page 1 of Xilinx's XAPP551. That seems to suggest a sort of two-block based approach, which I can't quite understand.

You seem to be asking about the two distinct methods used for obtaining the detected sequence from a Viterbi.
The first, using traceback, stores the decision of each state for each step of the Viterbi, meaning a single bit per state per step for a binary Viterbi trellis. For N states in a binary trellis, that means storing N bits per Viterbi step. Then, at the end of demod, start from the ending state S(k) at time k (by known closing bits or by tail biting or ...) and see what state it came from, based on its decision made at the prior step - call this S(k-1). Then, looking at the decision made when going into S(k-1) at that time offset, you get pointed to state S(k-2), etc.
The second, using a sliding window of path memory, relies on divergences in the trellis closing within some number of Viterbi steps (e.g. your 5K number). The output can be taken from a fixed state to avoid having to check which state's path memory is used to output the Viterbi decision. The length of the path memory can be shorted without increasing BER if you want to compute which state has the best accumulated metric after each Viterbi step, but this is costly compared to simply increasing path memory of all states by a bit. Upon completing the Viterbi demod, the last state (again, by known closing bits, tail-biting, etc), the path memory of the last state is used to get the remaining bits all at once. For example, I recall using 32 bit path memory in an 8 state Viterbi trellis, which meant updating 32x8 bits every step and outputting a decision out of one of the states (fixed) that had a delay of 32 samples compared to the current input sample.
The former uses more memory and requires a traceback operation at the end to recover the decoded bitstream. The path memory approach uses less memory but copies that memory each Viterbi step, resulting in more bits toggled (more power, wider bitwidth copied around in the updates each step). Path memory works well in a HW implementation while the traceback approach may lend itself to DSP implementation, especially with a Viterbi step accelerator. That said, I'd be cautious about over-generalizing which is better for HW vs DSP, as it depends on your particular application and resources.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm struggling to follow what you wrote. Could you perhaps recommend a book or other reference that covers this topic?

Sorry, I don't have a reference on this topic.

Just did a quick check of my Digital Communications text by Proakis. He has a description of the "path memory" approach I mentioned, though it's also in paragraph form without elaboration in diagram/equations. At least it's another description for you.

Yes, I have that book and have read through the section on Viterbi decoding. I sort of generally follow the discussion, but am not left with any real understanding of how to implement what is discussed.
